# Sub Chart on Teechart Active X

Tags: activex, teechart

I need a sample code where I can use the tool of SUB CHART. When ever I try to add it in my code it give me parent nulll issue and give access violation in the sample code provided by dragging point. Please can anyone help me with the sample code with sub chart having different series.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1):

There is an example using a SubChart in the Features Demo program shipped with the TeeChart ActiveX installation.
You can find the Features Demo program in your TeeChart ActiveX installation folder, at \Examples\Visual Basic\TeeChartAXv2014Demo\TeeChartFeatureDemo.exe
And the concrete example using the SubChart tool can be found at the "All Features" tab, following the "Welcome !\Tools\SubCharts" route.